# How to document additional models in Swagger for an inaccessible Controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have a controller that I have to keep generic by having it accept a `String` as `@RequestBody` and return a String, i.e., `String processRequest(@RequestBody String json) {...}`

**I don't have control over the source code of that controller, but I can get to it programmatically.**

The real objects that are going to be passed in and returned are defined elsewhere in a series of request messages: `RequestMessage1.java`, `RequestMessage2.java`, etc. Responses are likewise: `Response1.java`, `Response2.java1`.

The controller also hands off the processing of these requests to a `Processor` that looks something like this (`Request1Processor.java`): `Response1 process(RequestMessage1 message)`.

My question is this.

Is there a way to configure swagger such that it exposes the REST controller class's endpoint, i.e, `processRequest`, but shows all these Processor classes with their inputs and outputs as the documentation for that controller?

I saw as part of documentation the ability to add models that are not "reachable". I tried the method that's in documentation like this:

```
@Autowired
private TypeResolver typeResolver;

@Bean
public Docket api() {
  return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
      .select()
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
      .paths(PathSelectors.any())
      .build()
      .additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve(Date.class));
}
```

However, the additional Date model did not show up in swagger-ui.html.

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, is there a way to somehow show that `RequestMessage1` type will have a response with `Response1`?

Comment: Have you tried your implementation with other classes than `Date`?

Answer (score 12):

`Date` class was an unfavourable example to test because it is treated as a [string](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/).

> **Data Types**
>
> ...
>
> - string (this includes **dates** and files)

Try it again with real models you want to document additionally:

```
@Bean
public Docket api(TypeResolver typeResolver) {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
          .select()
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())
          .build()
          .additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve(RequestMessage1.class, Response1.class)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful.  How do I create a ModelRef(...) that refers to that type?

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to extend the already existing docket object instead of creating a new one.

Here is a solution:

```
import com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;

@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    private final TypeResolver typeResolver;

    @Autowired
    public SwaggerConfiguration(TypeResolver typeResolver) {
        this.typeResolver = typeResolver;
    }

    @Autowireda
    public void createAdditionalModelDocumentation(Docket docket) {
        docket.additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve(RequestMessage1.class),
                                typeResolver.resolve(Response1.class));
    }

}
```